# Function doesn't return anything (async?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add XPATH evaluation into my form. When user fills XPATH, it's evaluated on a server using AJAX and then return `true` or `false`.

The problem is that this function seems to return `undefined` allways. I suppose it's because of asynchronious behaviour of JS so I used `$.when` but it didn't helped.

```
function evalXpath(xpath) {
    var test = $.post('/api/test-xpath/', {'xpath': xpath});
    test.done(function (data) {
        console.log('BEFORE RETURN '+Boolean(data['success']));
        return Boolean(data['success']);
    })
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_xpath').on('change', function () {
        var xpath = $("#id_xpath").val();
        $.when(evalXpath(xpath)).done(function (evaluated) {
            console.log('RETURNED '+evaluated);
            $('#xpath-valid').text(evaluated ? 'VALID' : 'INVALID');
        });


    });

});
```

The console output (as you can see, it's still asynchronious):

[image]

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *really* close. A couple of things:

1. You forgot to return the promise out of `evalXpath`.
2. To get proper promise value chaining (e.g., in order for your value from the callback inside `evalXpath` to then become the resolution value of the promise it returns), use `then`, not `done`.
3. Then when using `evalXpath`, there's no need for `$.when`.

So:

```
function evalXpath(xpath) {
    var test = $.post('/api/test-xpath/', {'xpath': xpath});
    return test.then(function (data) {
//  ^^^^^^      ^^^^
        console.log('BEFORE RETURN '+Boolean(data['success']));
        return Boolean(data['success']);
    })
}

// ...
evalXpath(xpath).then(function (evaluated) {
//               ^^^^ (this one could be `done`, but let's be consistent)
```